# how can i connect to internet via usb dodge of a wireless keyboard?

Tags: wifi, keyboard, mouse, wireless-adapter, usb-hub

As we know RPi A+ has only on usb slot.

and to connect all these (keyboard, mouse, wifi adapter) devices i will need a USB hub, 
by default most people needs wifi and keyboard at least.

so the question is, may i configure the keyboards usb transpmitter to accept wifi signals? or i need to use them separately?

PS: i dont want to believe that the developers forgot about this case

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but some usb keyboards do come with a usb hub built in so you could add a usb wifi adaptor to a usb keyboard that hosted its own usb hub. I would worry about power. Your best bet is to attached a powered USB hub and connect everything to that.

Comment: *i dont want to believe that the developers forgot* -> I am sure it is on purpose, lol.  If this is a major issue for you, it's **you that forgot** when you decided to buy a board with only one jack.  I would buy a model A right now if they came with onboard ethernet.  Since they clearly do not, I am left having to choose something else (such as the rpi B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless keyboards could operate by using radio frequency (RF) or infrared (IR). RF techniques range from 27 MHz to up to 2.4 GHz (according to wikipedia). With Bluetooth being a widely used technology. While both WiFi and Bluetooth share the 2.4 GHz band they differ both in technical aspects as well as in their objective.

So in short: Your (presumed) Bluetooth dongle of the wireless keyboard is not going to double as an WiFi dongle.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to solve this problem is to use an USB hub. USB rf transmitter is not suitable for transferring WiFi. While *technically* it could, you'd probably have to upload custom firmware to it, which is nearly impossible to a normal user.